# How to take inputs from a from like this in jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have created a form in JSP. The jsp code is as follows -

```
<form>                  
<tr>
                <th>From Time</th>
                <th>To Time</th>
                <th>Phase</th>
                <th>Description</th>

            </tr>

            <%
                for (int time = 9; time < 23; time++) {
            %>
            <tr>

                <td id=<%out.print("tohr_" + time);%>><%=time%></td>
                <td id=<%out.print("fromhr_" + (time + 1));%>><%=time + 1%></td>

                <td><select id=<%out.print("phase_" + time);%>>
                        <option value="Select">Select</option>
                        <option value="Analysis">Analysis</option>
                        <option value="Design">Design</option>
                        <option value="Coding">Coding</option>
                        <option value="Testing">Testing</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select></td>

                <td><textarea id=<%out.print("desc_" + time);%> rows="4"
                        cols="50"></textarea></td>

            </tr>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </table>
</form>
```

The above JSP code is intended to take multiple inputs from the user. When the user clicks on submit button; the control will be passed to a servlet where the data will be retrieved from that JSP page and displayed in servlet. Following is my servlet code -

```
        for (int time = 9; time < 23; time++) {
        tohr = request.getParameter("tohr_" + time);
        out.print(request.getParameter("tohr_" + time));
        out.print(request.getAttribute("tohr_" + time));
        obj.setToHour(tohr);

        fromhr = request.getParameter("fromhr_" + time);
        out.print(request.getParameter("fromhr_" + time));
        out.print(request.getAttribute("fromhr_" + time));
        obj.setFromHour(fromhr);

        phase = request.getParameter("phase_" + time);
        out.print(request.getParameter("phase_" + time));
        out.print(request.getAttribute("phase_" + time));
        obj.setPhase(phase);

        desc = request.getParameter("desc_" + time);
        out.print(request.getParameter("desc_" + time));
        out.print(request.getAttribute("desc_" + time));
        obj.setDescription(desc);

        obj.setDate("12/12/2012");
        obj.setCreationDate("30/09/2015");
        obj.setUpdateDate("00/00/0000");

        ts.add(obj);
    }
```

I have checked for both getParameter() and getAttribute(). Both of the values return null in this condition. Please help.

Comment: where is the `form` tag?

Comment: For `request.getParameter()` to work, the form element must be given a name, so the value of `<select name="<%out.print("phase_" + time);%>">` can be retrieved by `request.getParameter("phase_" + time)`.

Comment: @Nikos Paraskevopoulos  Yes Nikos. I corrected and tried your suggestion however, it is still giving me null value.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing one code example for sending table data to server that will help you understand what you are missing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form name=login method="get" action="myServlet">
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td id="td1"><input type="text" name="td1" value="data1" style="border: none"></td>
    <td id="td2"><input type="text" name="td2" value="data2" style="border: none"></td>  
    <td id="td3"><input type="text" name="td3" value="data3" style="border: none"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="td4"><input type="text" name="td4" value="data4" style="border: none"></td>
    <td id="td5"><input type="text" name="td5" value="data5" style="border: none"></td>  
    <td id="td6"><input type="text" name="td6" value="data6" style="border: none"></td>
  </tr>
 
</table>
<button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

On click of login button,you can see the url( like this http://../WebAppName/myServlet?td1=data1&td2=data2&td3=data3&td4=data4&td5=data5&td6=data6) which will have all the data that you can retrieve at server using `request.getParameter("paramterName")`.
If you are not interested to append the data into url,simply use post in place of get .

```
<form name=login method="post" action="myServlet">
```